# How Cassandra 3.x version assign connection to different microservices connecting with same keyspace using same user id

Tags: cassandra, microservices, connection-pooling

I am really new to cassandra, we have 5 microservices which are connection to one cassandra cluster. We have a cassandra Cluster of 6 Node.
In our architecture all 5 microservices are connecting to same cluster and same keySpace, using same user id and password. 
when i looked at the Cassandra cluster object I could see, java driver is using protocol V4, 1024 maxReequestperConnection, max connection is also 1
I need to understand how come 5 microservices are connecting using one connection and what is the max number of cql we can fire from each microservice.
currently one of microservices intermittently throws BusyPoolException.
Please help me to understand how connection are made between cluster and microservice and what is the max number request we can send from each microservice

Comment: can you post the actual property names? I am new as well. Going through couple of books and courses at the moment. Because I have a suspicion  that ```connection pool``` configurations you mentioning are for the client side. It is not a restriction of the Cassandra server. So one microservice does not have any impact at all regarding how the other microservice configures its connection pool.

Comment: in microservices we are not setting any properties for PoolingOptions. we are using CassandraTemplate Class for query CRUD operation, but I want to understand how cassandra managing connection to one keyspace by 5 microservices.